# Network share mapping not working correctly Win8/2012

Tags: network-share, windows-server-2012, windows-8

We have a straight forward domain logon script with a line along the lines of
`net use s: \\server\share` 
However, this isn't working correctly with Windows 8 / 2012 machines.

The strange thing is that if you attempt to do this manually on one of the affected machines it will complain that the drive is already mapped - you can see the mapping from the command line however it does not show in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Try doing a `net use s: /delete` first.

Comment: Although I haven't mentioned it does do this - we recently changed the location of the s: drive so to ensure everyone migrated over correctly we do a delete first.

Comment: Could be that the S: letter is already used? check the disk management first or try a different drive letter.

Comment: No the S: isn't already used - and if it is the mapping is deleted. I'm looking into Win 8 handling it differently depending on user/admin privileges.

Comment: Just a suggestion: why don't you use separate group policy object for mapping net shares instead of doing this with a script?

Comment: This is an option I will take a look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hunch: Is the user local administrator on his/her Win8 workstation? The reason I'm asking:
Logon Scripts actually run elevated if the user is a local administrator. This in effect performs the drive mapping in the user's elevated session, not the "normal" session.

Microsoft's recommendation is to use Group Policy Preferences for drive maps, as these run in the correct session.

You can test this theory out by (temporarily) removing the user from the local admin group on the workstation where he/she logs on to.

Comment: Not all users are local admin on the workstation - I believe this may be part of the issue. Will check out GP preferences.

Comment: Group Policy drive mapping worked perfectly.